# Excessive leaking from injectors

Tags: fuel-injectors, vacuum-leak, fuel-leak

I changed the timing chain and tensioner in a 1.6hdi diesel, so twin camshafts has a timing chain and tensioner connecting them. The chain didn't break rather it slipped 5 notches. The repair seemed to go well. I put other parts back together. The engine starts well but I get thick white smoke coming from it seems everywhere including the exhaust.

The injectors are leaking like crazy not just a small leak but pouring diesel.

I drain the "oil" and it turns out there's about 2 litres of diesel in the oil.

This is from running the van for maybe 2 mins max. So it seems an extreme amount of fuel is getting into the engine.

Can you diagnose. Here's a few ideas.

Damaged or blocked injectors(s)

Valve damage from when the engine was run with a slipped chain

Air leak somewhere possibly inlet manifold seals.

Injectors seals leaking.

Bad sensor like camshaft sensor.

I'm getting what I assume is a lot of blow by in the engine, a lot of gas build up and coughing, spluttering noises, and almost a runaway situation when shutting the engine off.

Maybe I just need to seal the injectors better, cut the seats better and secure it down tighter.

Comment: This doesn’t sound like an injector issue to me.  Tell us which engine  and vehicle you have.  Hoes it have injector pumps internal to the engine?

Comment: 1.6hdi Peugeot. I think what happened is at least 1 injector has failed, stuck open. The fuel has got into the engine and hence contaminated the oil. I know now that the turbo has blown as a result and a runaway situation was very close to happening. This is all because failed injectors I suspect. I will get them tested.

Comment: It still doesn’t make sense. If the injector is leaking, the diesel will just go into the cylinder, it couldn’t get into the oil.  I think something is leaking before the injector.

Comment: Can the fuel not get into the oil past the piston rings or valves?

Comment: Here's a quote I found.  Fuel injector pintle, ball or disc seat leaks as well as the bottom O-ring leak on a side feed injector will cause fuel to escape into the intake manifold. From the manifold the fuel will run down to the intake valves. If an intake valve is in the open position that fuel will enter the cylinder where it will leak past the rings and eventually mix with the engine oil.

Comment: You may well be correct, I don’t know much about this engine, but the quantity you were talking about in such a short time just seems unlikely.